# Converting plain javascript to angular component

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to angular and working on my own project as a follow along with some courses I found this great animation on codepen here is a link :  [codepen](https://codepen.io/aaroniker/pen/eYzZzpV)

That I want to add to my application, the idea is when I click publish or in my case "upload" I get a window to upload a file and then the animation resumes exactly like in the codepen link.

the author of the codepen link was so kind to include very detailed and great code, but it has javascript obviously because of the dynamic nature of the button, so adding something like this ( the javascript code ) to the angular application is considered bad, since angular should be the only thing manipulating the dom.

My question is how do I implement something like this completely in angular?

Here is the code :

```
    <button class="publish-button">
        <div class="icon">
            <svg class="cloud" viewBox="0 0 20 24">
                <path d="M18.3385 10.5888C18.364 10.6828 18.415 10.7769 18.415 10.8709C18.4706 11.1525 18.499 11.4387 18.5 11.7258C18.497 11.9925 18.4714 12.2584 18.4235 12.5208C18.4065 12.6063 18.364 12.6832 18.364 12.7687C18.322 12.9366 18.2709 13.1021 18.211 13.2645L18.109 13.5124C18.0342 13.6772 17.949 13.8371 17.854 13.9911L17.735 14.1792C17.7228 14.2031 17.7086 14.226 17.6925 14.2476L17.65 14.2903C17.2541 14.8211 16.7408 15.252 16.1507 15.5488C15.5605 15.8455 14.9098 16 14.25 16H11.7H8.3H5.75C5.09021 16 4.43948 15.8455 3.84934 15.5488C3.25921 15.252 2.74588 14.8211 2.35 14.2903L2.3075 14.2305C2.29145 14.2089 2.27723 14.186 2.265 14.1621L2.146 13.974C2.051 13.82 1.96582 13.6601 1.891 13.4953L1.789 13.2474C1.72909 13.085 1.67801 12.9195 1.636 12.7516C1.619 12.6661 1.5765 12.5892 1.5765 12.5037C1.52957 12.247 1.50398 11.9867 1.5 11.7258C1.50364 11.453 1.53209 11.1812 1.585 10.9137C1.602 10.8196 1.6615 10.7256 1.6615 10.6316C1.70084 10.4657 1.75198 10.3028 1.8145 10.1443C1.857 10.0417 1.8995 9.95622 1.9675 9.82799C2.0355 9.69977 2.1035 9.56299 2.1715 9.45186C2.2395 9.34073 2.3075 9.2467 2.3925 9.14412C2.4775 9.04153 2.571 8.92186 2.656 8.82782C2.741 8.73379 2.8345 8.65685 2.928 8.57137L3.2425 8.30637L3.5485 8.04991C3.66862 7.97598 3.79357 7.91029 3.9225 7.8533L4.254 7.69942C4.39284 7.64771 4.53479 7.60488 4.679 7.5712C4.79324 7.5374 4.90969 7.51169 5.0275 7.49426L5.1805 7.45152C5.52733 6.4437 6.17792 5.56967 7.04172 4.95105C7.90552 4.33244 8.93957 4 10 4C11.0604 4 12.0945 4.33244 12.9583 4.95105C13.8221 5.56967 14.4727 6.4437 14.8195 7.45152L15.015 7.54555C15.1328 7.56298 15.2493 7.58869 15.3635 7.62249C15.5077 7.65617 15.6497 7.699 15.7885 7.75071L16.12 7.90459C16.2489 7.96158 16.3739 8.02727 16.494 8.1012L16.8 8.30637L17.1145 8.58846C17.208 8.67395 17.293 8.74234 17.3865 8.84492C17.48 8.9475 17.65 9.09283 17.65 9.16121C17.65 9.2296 17.752 9.28944 17.8285 9.40912C17.905 9.5288 17.9815 9.67412 18.0325 9.78525C18.0835 9.89638 18.143 9.99896 18.1855 10.1015C18.248 10.2601 18.2992 10.4229 18.3385 10.5888Z" />
            </svg>
            <svg viewBox="0 0 20 24">
                <path class="line" d="M10 23V10" />
                <path class="arrow" d="M10 10L7.5 12.5" />
                <path class="arrow" d="M10 10L12.5 12.5" />
                <path class="tick" d="M6.5 10.5L9 13L13.5 7.5" />
            </svg>
        </div>
        <div class="text">
            <span class="normal">Publish</span>
            <span class="progress">Loading</span>
            <span class="done">Done</span>
        </div>
    </button>
    
    <!-- dribbble - twitter -->
    <a class="dribbble" href="https://dribbble.com/ai" target="_blank"><img src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/assets/dribbble-ball-mark-2bd45f09c2fb58dbbfb44766d5d1d07c5a12972d602ef8b32204d28fa3dda554.svg" alt=""></a>
    <a class="twitter" target="_top" href="https://twitter.com/aaroniker_me"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="72" height="72" viewBox="0 0 72 72"><path d="M67.812 16.141a26.246 26.246 0 0 1-7.519 2.06 13.134 13.134 0 0 0 5.756-7.244 26.127 26.127 0 0 1-8.313 3.176A13.075 13.075 0 0 0 48.182 10c-7.229 0-13.092 5.861-13.092 13.093 0 1.026.118 2.021.338 2.981-10.885-.548-20.528-5.757-26.987-13.679a13.048 13.048 0 0 0-1.771 6.581c0 4.542 2.312 8.551 5.824 10.898a13.048 13.048 0 0 1-5.93-1.638c-.002.055-.002.11-.002.162 0 6.345 4.513 11.638 10.504 12.84a13.177 13.177 0 0 1-3.449.457c-.846 0-1.667-.078-2.465-.231 1.667 5.2 6.499 8.986 12.23 9.09a26.276 26.276 0 0 1-16.26 5.606A26.21 26.21 0 0 1 4 55.976a37.036 37.036 0 0 0 20.067 5.882c24.083 0 37.251-19.949 37.251-37.249 0-.566-.014-1.134-.039-1.694a26.597 26.597 0 0 0 6.533-6.774z"></path></svg></a>
```

```
    .publish-button {
        --color: #fff;
        --icon-color: #fff;
        --background-default: #0376FF;
        //
        --text-normal-o: 1;
        --text-normal-y: 0px;
        --text-progress-o: 0;
        --text-progress-y: -8px;
        --text-done-o: 0;
        --text-done-y: -8px;
        --icon-arrow-offset: 0px;
        --icon-arrow-y: 0px;
        --icon-cloud-y: 0px;
        --icon-tick-offset: 11px;
        --icon-line-offset: 21px;
        --icon-circle-scale: 0;
        -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        outline: none;
        border: none;
        background: none;
        padding: 10px 20px 10px 12px;
        border-radius: 9px;
        overflow: hidden;
        margin: 0;
        font-family: inherit;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: 500;
        line-height: 20px;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        cursor: pointer;
        position: relative;
        color: var(--color);
        background: var(--background, var(--background-default));
        .icon {
            width: 20px;
            height: 20px;
            pointer-events: none;
            position: relative;
            margin-right: 8px;
            &:before {
                content: '';
                position: absolute;
                left: 1px;
                top: 1px;
                right: 1px;
                bottom: 1px;
                opacity: .25;
                border-radius: 50%;
                background: var(--icon-color);
                transform: scale(var(--icon-circle-scale)) translateZ(0);
            }
            svg {
                display: block;
                width: 20px;
                height: 24px;
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                &.cloud {
                    fill: var(--icon-color);
                    fill-opacity: .25;
                    transform: translateY(var(--icon-cloud-y)) translateZ(0);
                }
                &:not(.cloud) {
                    fill: none;
                    stroke: var(--icon-color);
                    stroke-width: 1.5;
                    stroke-linecap: round;
                    path {
                        &.line,
                        &.arrow {
                            transform: translateY(var(--icon-arrow-y)) translateZ(0);
                        }
                        &.line {
                            stroke-dasharray: 13px;
                            stroke-dashoffset: var(--icon-line-offset);
                        }
                        &.arrow {
                            stroke-dasharray: 4px;
                            stroke-dashoffset: var(--icon-arrow-offset);
                        }
                        &.tick {
                            stroke-dasharray: 11px;
                            stroke-dashoffset: var(--icon-tick-offset);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .text {
            position: relative;
            span {
                display: block;
                opacity: var(--o, var(--text-normal-o));
                transform: translateY(var(--y, var(--text-normal-y))) translateZ(0);
                &:not(.normal) {
                    position: absolute;
                    left: 0;
                    top: 0;
                }
                &.progress {
                    --o: var(--text-progress-o);
                    --y: var(--text-progress-y);
                }
                &.done {
                    --o: var(--text-done-o);
                    --y: var(--text-done-y);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    html {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    }
    
    * {
        box-sizing: inherit;
        &:before,
        &:after {
            box-sizing: inherit;
        }
    }
    
    // Center & dribbble
    body {
        min-height: 100vh;
        display: flex;
        font-family: 'Inter', Arial;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        background: #F6F8FF;
        .dribbble {
            position: fixed;
            display: block;
            right: 20px;
            bottom: 20px;
            img {
                display: block;
                height: 28px;
            }
        }
        .twitter {
            position: fixed;
            display: block;
            right: 64px;
            bottom: 14px;
            svg {
                width: 32px;
                height: 32px;
                fill: #1da1f2;
            }
        }
    }
```

```
const { set, to, fromTo } = gsap

const loadingTime = 5000
const resetTime = 5000

document.querySelectorAll('.publish-button').forEach(button => {
    let tweenHover = to(button, {
        paused: true,
        keyframes: [{
            '--icon-arrow-y': '-2px',
            '--icon-line-offset': '23px',
            duration: .15
        }, {
            '--icon-arrow-y': '0px',
            '--icon-line-offset': '21px',
            duration: .3
        }]
    }),
    interval;

    button.addEventListener('pointerenter', e => {
        if(button.classList.contains('animated')) {
            return
        }
        tweenHover.restart()
        interval = setInterval(() => tweenHover.restart(), 1000)
    });

    button.addEventListener('pointerleave', e => clearInterval(interval))

    button.addEventListener('click', e => {
        e.preventDefault()

        if(button.classList.contains('animated')) {
            return
        }
        button.classList.add('animated')

        let text = button.querySelector('.text'),
            normal = text.querySelector('.normal'),
            progress = text.querySelector('.progress'),
            done = text.querySelector('.done'),
            normalWidth = normal.offsetWidth

        clearInterval(interval)
        tweenHover.pause()

        let cloud = button.querySelector('.cloud'),
            cloudInterval,
            clone = cloud.cloneNode(true)

        gsap.to(button, {
            '--icon-cloud-y': '32px',
            duration: .15
        })

        cloudInterval = setInterval(() => {
            createCloud(clone, button.querySelector('.icon'))
        }, 400)

        let tweenArrow = fromTo(button, {
            '--icon-arrow-y': '0px',
            '--icon-line-offset': '21px',
            duration: .15
        }, {
            repeat: -1,
            keyframes: [{
                '--icon-arrow-y': '-6px',
                '--icon-line-offset': '24px',
                duration: .6,
            }, {
                '--icon-arrow-y': '0px',
                '--icon-line-offset': '21px',
                duration: .85,
                ease: 'power2.out'
            }]
        })

        to(button, {
            onStart() {
                to(text, {
                    width: progress.offsetWidth,
                    duration: .15
                })
            },
            '--text-normal-o': 0,
            '--text-normal-y': '8px',
            duration: .25
        })

        to(button, {
            '--text-progress-o': 1,
            '--text-progress-y': '0px',
            duration: .3,
            delay: .1
        })

        setTimeout(() => {
            tweenArrow.pause()
            clearInterval(cloudInterval)
            to(button, {
                onStart() {
                    to(text, {
                        width: done.offsetWidth,
                        duration: .15
                    })
                },
                '--text-progress-o': 0,
                '--text-progress-y': '8px',
                duration: .25
            })
            to(button, {
                duration: .25,
                keyframes: [{
                    '--icon-line-offset': '13px'
                }, {
                    '--icon-arrow-offset': '4px'
                }]
            })
            to(button, {
                '--text-done-o': 1,
                '--text-done-y': '0px',
                duration: .3,
                delay: .1
            })
            to(button, {
                '--icon-tick-offset': '0px',
                duration: .25,
                delay: .3
            })
            to(button, {
                '--icon-circle-scale': 1,
                duration: .7,
                delay: .2,
                ease: 'elastic.out(1, .75)'
            })
            setTimeout(() => {
                reset(button, normalWidth, text)
            }, resetTime)
        }, loadingTime)
    })
})

function createCloud(node, parent) {
    let elem = node.cloneNode(true)
    parent.appendChild(elem)
    set(elem, {
        x: gsap.utils.random(-8, 8),
        y: -36
    })
    to(elem, {
        y: 36,
        duration: gsap.utils.random(.4, 1.5),
        onComplete() {
            elem.remove()
        }
    })
}

function reset(button, normalWidth, text) {
    to(button, {
        onStart() {
            to(text, {
                width: normalWidth,
                duration: .15,
                clearProps: true
            })
        },
        '--text-done-o': 0,
        '--text-done-y': '8px',
        duration: .25
    })
    fromTo(button, {
        '--text-normal-y': '-8px'
    }, {
        '--text-normal-o': 1,
        '--text-normal-y': '0px',
        duration: .3,
        delay: .1
    })
    to(button, {
        keyframes: [{
            '--icon-tick-offset': '11px',
            '--icon-circle-scale': 0,
            '--icon-arrow-y': '0px',
            duration: .2
        }, {
            '--icon-cloud-y': '0px',
            '--icon-line-offset': '21px',
            duration: .2
        }, {
            '--icon-arrow-offset': '0px',
            duration: .15
        }],
        clearProps: true,
        onComplete() {
            button.classList.remove('animated')
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: GSAP is not exactly plain javascript,  and it doing all the animating.  This could be a nice little component or directive though,  look at tutorials on GSAP with Angular like - https://dev.to/nicolalc/gsap-animations-in-angular-animation-directives-14pi.

Comment: This is pretty advanced stuff for me I think, is there a way to implement this without learning GASP ?

Comment: I'm sure this can be done with just angular,  but I would suggest a more basic start to angular.   Start by just creating a component with SVG in the template.  You can bind the attributes and do all kinds of cool things with just that.  Something like this - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-svg-btn-test

Comment: Hey, @Dylan thank you so much for your help, the implementation you did will work perfectly for me, but I was wondering how do I synchronize the click to uploading a file and the processing to a file being uploaded and the done to the file being done uploading?

Comment: That gets a bit complex,  but you can follow this tutorial - https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-file-upload/.   The important bit is where you subscribe to the post.